# Display object from NSMutableArray in UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, uilabel

I'm trying to display the field 'field_friendbio' in my UILabel. How should I write this line? self.mapFriendData is an NSMutableArray (data is passed to self.mapFriendData from a previous controller).

Right now, I have:

**.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *mapFriendData;
```

**.m**

```
self.userBio.text = self.mapFriendData[@"field_friendbio"][@"und"][0][@"safe_value"];
```

But that only works with NSDictionary.

**The data output:**

```
  "field_friendbio" =         {
            und =             (
                                {
                    format = "<null>";
                    "safe_value" = "Hi my name is Blair. ";
                    value = "Hi my name is Blair. ";
                }
            );
        };
```

Before I call it to the UILabel, mapFriendData is:

```
THIS IS MAP FRIEND DATA (
        {
        body =         (
        );
        changed = 1462155513;
        cid = 0;
        comment = 2;
        "comment_count" = 0;
        created = 1462155513;
        data = "a:1:{s:7:\"overlay\";i:1;}";
        "field_address1" =         {
            und =             (
                                {
                    format = "<null>";
                    "safe_value" = "1275 This Street, LA, California";
                    value = "1275 This Street, LA, California";
                }
            );
        };
        "field_friendbio" =         {
            und =             (
                                {
                    format = "<null>";
                    "safe_value" = "Hi my name is Blair.";
                    value = "Hi my name is Blair.";
                }
            );
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, it's an array, so you need to provide the index of the dict you want to get first:

```
self.userBio.text = self.mapFriendData[0][@"field_friendbio"][@"und"][0][@"safe_value"];
                                       ^
                                    "index of your field_friendbio dict"
```

Comment: this doesn't crash my app, and the data comes through, but for some reason my label is empty? And when I log this line:     self.userBio.text = self.mapFriendData[0][@"field_friendbio"][@"und"][0][@"safe_value"];
 The data comes through loud and clear, as you'd expect. What gives? haha

Comment: @BlairWarner 1. can u provide the whole `self.mapFriendData` u get in this controller before assigning to `self.userBio.text `? And make sure the data indeed passed from your previous controller. 2. Where did u assign the `self.userBio.text`, does `self.userBio` allocated at that time?

Comment: See edit above. self.mapFriendData is definitely present. UILabel is assigned in viewDidLoad.

Comment: @BlairWarner try to assign the UILabel value in `-viewDidAppear`. I'm afraid ur `self.mapFriendData` has not passed from previous vc when u use it in `-viewDidLoad` (unless u pass it in init method). If this way still does not work, debug the layout of ur UILabel, maybe sth wrong w/ it.